# Compatibility with both Chez and Chicken Scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme, chez-scheme

I'm trying to write a program compatible with both Chez and Chicken Scheme. Starting with something maximally simple:

```
(c1) R:\>type  hello.ss
(display "hello, world\n")

(c1) R:\>csc hello.ss

(c1) R:\>hello
hello, world

(c1) R:\>"C:\Program Files\Chez Scheme 9.5.8\bin\a6nt\scheme.exe" --program hello.ss
Exception: invalid top-level program import subform (display "hello, world\n") at line 1, char 1 of hello.ss
```

Chicken is happy with the simplest version, but Chez isn't. Okay, I know a way to make Chez happy:

```
(c1) R:\>type  hello2.ss
(import (rnrs))
(display "hello, world\n")

(c1) R:\>"C:\Program Files\Chez Scheme 9.5.8\bin\a6nt\scheme.exe" --program hello2.ss
hello, world
```

But does Chicken like that version?

```
(c1) R:\>csc hello2.ss

Syntax error (import): cannot import from undefined module

        rnrs

        Expansion history:

        <syntax>          (##core#begin (import (rnrs)))
        <syntax>          (import (rnrs))       <--

Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 70: ""c:/chicken/bin/chicken.exe" "hello2.ss" -output-file "hello2.c""
```

Sadly, no.

How can I write a program that both implementations are happy with?

Comment: Have you tried with `#!r6rs` as the first line before `import`?

Comment: @Sylwester That gives an error: Error: (line 1) invalid `#!' token: "r6rs"

Comment: Chicken is R5RS, and there's a R7RS egg available to support that version of the standard. It doesn't claim to support R6RS.

Comment: `(import (scheme))` works in both, but since Chez is R6RS and Chicken is R5RS/R7RS, it'll be up to you to stick to a compatible language subset.

Comment: If [this is to be believed](https://docs.scheme.org/surveys/cond-expand/), Chez doesn't support SRFI-0 `cond-expand`,  so you can't use it to conditionally import the appropriate modules depending on scheme implementation... I thought I was on to something, too.

Comment: Better to write something compatible with one of the official revisions and require a scheme that supports it. It's the same with Python 2 vs 3 and Perl5 vs Raku. You simply cannot expect random code that works in one to also work in the other since there are not compatible. What Peter suggests is basically like making a polygot, code that happens to run in two different runtimes.

Comment: On linux there is https://github.com/scheme-live/live that implements a `json2scm` program that runs on several Scheme implementations. Also see https://github.com/amirouche/scheme-united

Comment: @amirouche How does it work around the scheme version differences? Eg R5RS does not support `import`. Why json2scm. Sounds a little farfetched to write code in json 

Comment: json2scm will translate json to scheme expression according to SRFI-180 mapping. CHICKEN 5 support imports. Look for chicken cond-expand at https://github.com/scheme-live/live/blob/hello-schemer/live/unstable.sld

Comment: JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, SCM is referring to in this case to Scheme expressions.